# $\lambda \in K$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$ iff $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial $P$

Tags: proof-verification

**Statement:**

> Assume $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$. Let $\phi: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map.
>
> Then $\lambda \in K$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$ iff $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial $P$.

**Proof:**

Let $M$ be the matrix of $\phi$ and let $\lambda \in K$ be arbitrary.

We have $P(\lambda) = \det(\lambda E_n - M) = 0$ iff $\lambda Id_V - \phi$ is not bijective (and not injective). This follows from the theorems ...

This is equivalent to

$Eig_\lambda(\phi) = kern(\lambda Id_V - \phi) \neq 0$, which means that the eigenspace of $\lambda$ is not the nullspace. Therefore, $\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue of $\phi$.

The theorems he mentioned are the following:

> Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $det M \neq 0$.
> 2. The rows of $M$ are linear indepentent.
> 3. $M$ is invertible.
> 4. $rank(M) = n$.

and

> Assume $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $K$ with $dim(V) = n$ and $dim(W) = m$. Let $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map that can be denoted by the matrix $M$. Then the following statements are true:
>
> 1. $\phi$ is injective iff the columns of the matrix are linear independent.
> 2. $\phi$ is surjective iff the columns of the matrix generate $K^m$.
> 3. If $m = n$, then $\phi$ is bijective iff the columns of the matrix are a base of $K^m$, and this holds iff $M$ is invertible.

**Questions**

My question is: How do we know that $\phi$ is not injective given these two theorems and the argumentation above?

Comment: Linear operators on finite-dimensional vector spaces are injective iff they are surjective.

Comment: So by concluding that $\phi$ is not bijective, we also conclude that $\phi$ mustn't be either injective or surjective or both, but already concluding one of those properties already gives us the other one?

Comment: If $\dim V=n$ and $T:V\to V$ is a linear map, then by the rank-nullity theorem, $$\dim T(V) + \dim \ker(T) = n. $$
$T$ is injective iff $\dim\ker(T)=0$, and $T$ is surjective iff $\dim T(V)=n$.